# jQuery, bootstrap 3 forum on click brings doesn't leave comment

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap 3 website and I found an example code to use to create a forum. I found another source of code that is a comment section. I tried using append to take the text from the comment box and add it to below the first comment but right now when I click the comment button the text does not show up. I did a console.log and when i click the comment button the console.log shows up, so my issue is somewhere in the append i just dont know where.

I would like the page to go to the comment, obviously keep the collapse open, and for the text to appear.

I created a fiddle and heres my code

https://jsfiddle.net/mattmega4/chv94zwa/2/embedded/result/

```
$('#commentButton').on('click', function() {
    if($('#forumCommentSearchBox').val() ) {
      $('#forumCommentSearchBox').append($('.commentList li').val())
        console.log("bob the builder")
      $("#commentButton").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    }
     else{
      alert("idiot")
    }
  })



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>United Photographers Movement</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/forumComment.css">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.png"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a href ="index.html" class="navbar-brand">U.P.M.</a>
        <img src="assets/camera.png" class="pull-left">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-
target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class = "active"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>



            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = 
"dropdown">Options<b class="caret"></b></a>





                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li id=default><a  href="#">Change Theme</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>



<div id="bigpappa">
  <div class="container well">
    <div class="page-header page-heading">
      <h1 class="pull-left">Forums</h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb pull-right where-am-i">
        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
        <li class="active">List of topics</li>
      </ol>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="lead">Welcome to the United Photographers Movement! Here 
you can post general or specific photography questions as well as 
locations to shoot. Finally, you can also post examples of your work 
for critique. <b>Note</b> Please check older posts before you post your 
own to make sure your question isn't already answered!</p>
    <table class="table forum table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="cell-stat"></th>
          <th>
            <h3>Questions</h3>
          </th>
          <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Topics</th>
          <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Posts</th>
          <th class="cell-stat-2x hidden-xs hidden-sm">Last Post</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-question fa-2x text-
primary"></i></td>
          <td>
            <h4><a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a><br>
<small>General Questions</small></h4>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">9 
542</a></td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">89 
897</a></td>
          <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">John Doe</a>
<br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 months ago</small></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-question fa-2x text-
primary"></i></td>
          <td>
            <h4><a href="#">Specific Questions</a><br><small>Questions 
about specific cameras or techniques for specific locations etc...
</small></h4>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">9 
542</a></td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">89 
897</a></td>
          <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">John Doe</a>
<br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 months ago</small></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table forum table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="cell-stat"></th>
          <th>
            <h3>Locations</h3>
          </th>
          <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Topics</th>
          <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Posts</th>
          <th class="cell-stat-2x hidden-xs hidden-sm">Last Post</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x text-
primary"></i></td>
          <td>
            <h4><a href="#">Alabama</a><br><small>Search locations by 
state</small></h4>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a 
href="#">6532</a></td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a 
href="#">152123</a></td>
          <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">Jane Doe</a>
<br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 months ago</small></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-magic fa-2x text-
primary"></i></td>
          <td>
            <h4><a href="#">Alaska</a><br><small>Search locations by 
state</small></h4>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a 
href="#">6532</a></td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a 
href="#">152123</a></td>
          <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">Jane Doe</a>
<br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 years ago</small></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="table forum table-striped">

      <table class="table forum table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="cell-stat"></th>
            <th>
              <h3>Critique</h3>
            </th>
            <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Topics</th>
            <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Posts</th>
            <th class="cell-stat-2x hidden-xs hidden-sm">Last Post</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-question fa-2x 
text-primary"></i></td>
            <td>
              <h4 class="theBigCollapse" data-toggle="collapse"><a 
href="#">Get your work critiqued</a><br><small>Please link your 
photographs <b>DO NOT</b> try to upload!</small></h4>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a 
href="#">0</a></td>
            <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a 
href="#">0</a></td>
            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">John Doe</a>
<br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Never</small></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>





      </table>


      <div class="collapse">

        <div class="well">

          <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">

          <div class="firstPost">
          <div class="postHeading">
            <h3>My shot, Banff Pano</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="postBody">
            <p>
            Here is a shot of Banff Alberta, Canada.
            I took a series of photographs in the portrait orientation 
 and, using Lightroom and Photoshop, I stitched them together and 
adjusted the image to bring out more contrast and colors. The settings 
 are f/11 at 1/500s; ISO 280.
          </p>
          <p>
            I'm wondering if I should have used a wider aperture and 
let the background be a little more blurred
          </p>
          </div>
          <div class="postImage">
            <img src="assets/pano.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="postFooter">
            <p>
              Posted on 7/23/15 at 12:05PM
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>


</div> <!-- end of 8 -->

<div class="col-md-4">
  <h3>HELLO WORLD SCREAM</h3>
  <p>Something goes here</p>



</div>
</div> <!-- end of row -->
</div> <!-- end of well -->





<div class="well">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="detailBox pull-left">
    <div class="titleBox">
      <label>Comment and Critiques</label>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;
</button>
    </div>
    <div class="commentBox">

        <p class="taskDescription">Please only give constructive 
critique. Questions of location and camera settings are ok if the OP 
did not state in post.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="actionBox">
        <ul class="commentList">
            <li>
                <div class="commenterImage">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people/9" />
                </div>
                <div class="commentText">
                    <p class="">I like the contrasting sky with the 
 vibrant greens.</p> <span class="date sub-text">on March 5th,   
 2014</span>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="forumCommentSearchBox" class="form-control" 
type="text" placeholder="Your comments" />
            </div>

        </form>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
                <button id="commentButton" class="btn btn-
 default">Comment</button>
            </div>
</div>
</div>



<div class="col-md-4">
<p> Evil robots</p>
</div> <!-- end of md-4 -->


</div> <!-- end of row -->
</div> <!-- end of well -->

</div> <!-- end of collapse container -->





      </div>

    </table>


  </div>
  </div>







  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="navbar-text pull-left">
        Site built by Self Aware Machines
      </p>

  <p>
    <div class="input-group col-lg-3 pull-right">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search 
 Site"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
      </span>

    </div>
  </p>



    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script>



    <script>

  </body>
</html>


.detailBox {
    border:1px solid #bbb;

}
.titleBox {
    background-color:#fdfdfd;
    padding:10px;
}
.titleBox label{
  color:#444;
  margin:0;
  display:inline-block;
}

.commentBox {
    padding:10px;
    border-top:1px dotted #bbb;
}
.commentBox .form-group:first-child, .actionBox .form-group:first-child {
    width:80%;
}
.commentBox .form-group:nth-child(2), .actionBox .form-group:nth-child(2) {
    width:18%;
}
.actionBox .form-group * {
    width:100%;
}
.taskDescription {
    margin-top:10px 0;
}
.commentList {
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    max-height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.commentList li {
    margin:0;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.commentList li > div {
    display:table-cell;
}
.commenterImage {
    width:30px;
    margin-right:5px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
.commenterImage img {
    width:100%;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.commentText p {
    margin:0;
}
.sub-text {
    color:#aaa;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:11px;
}
.actionBox {
    border-top:1px dotted #bbb;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: To open the collapse and see the content its the last link that reads: "Get your work critiqued"

Comment: nothing happens clicking last link in demo...tried 2 browsers

Comment: You need to fix your example code because the section you're referring to (comment form) is currently hidden inside <div class="collapse"> and the example has several errors in general that need to be fixed: IE multiple body tags.

Comment: Im sorry I forgot to add one section of code in the jsfiddle....should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#commentButton').on('click', function() {
if($('#forumCommentSearchBox').val() ) {

  $('.commentList').append('<li><div class="commenterImage"> \
                                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people/9"> \
                              </div> \
                              <div class="commentText"> \
                                <p class="">'+$('#forumCommentSearchBox').val()+'</p> \
                                <span class="date sub-text">on March 5th, 2014</span> \
                              </div></li>');
    console.log("bob the builder");

}
 else{
  alert("idiot");
}
});
```